# Offline log analyser

Tags: log

I have many web server logs. How I can analyse it on mine host machine? Need offline analyser with GUI or Web interface, and with the ability to save reports.

Comment: Look at [webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) or [apacheviewer](http://www.apacheviewer.com/)

Comment: apacheviewer for windows,  but my OS is ubuntu( 
I try webalizer, maybe it's something that I need.

Comment: webalizer should be in the universe ubuntu archive.